# The prefix "cas" for element "cas:hazelcast-ticket-registry" is not bound

Tags: xml, spring, tomcat7, xml-namespaces, cas

I'm getting this error when I restart Tomcat7.  This is taken from my localhost.yymmdd.log.  I've examined the xml file it references but fail to see any error.  any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
Oct 20, 2015 11:32:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
Oct 20, 2015 11:32:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 
Oct 20, 2015 11:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 38 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketRegistry.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 91; The prefix "cas" for element "cas:hazelcast-ticket-registry" is not bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 91; The prefix "cas" for element "cas:hazelcast-ticket-registry" is not bound
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question. Please take care of formatting code and stack traces...

Comment: My guess is that the error message means exactly what it says, and that the XML parser examined the file more carefully than you did. But since you haven't given us a chance to examine the file, that can only be a guess.